# Delphi PNGImage - Image transparency is not pure

Tags: image, delphi, transparency

I am using PNG images as main image resource in my application. Since im using Delphi 7, i downloaded PNGImage lib and included it in project. I load images like this:

```
Form.image.Picture.LoadFromFile(PAnsiChar('\background.png'));
```

Image has transparent and semi transparent pixels on its border. The problem i get is that transparent pixels are filled with random zoomed part of my desktop with currently opened windows, while i expected to see what is actually located beneath form.

Additionally, form has this properties:

`BorderStyle: bsNone;
 TransparentColor: true;
 Visible: false;`

Here is a picture of current state (above black line) and desired:
[image: delphi transparency issue]

Can this be fixed somehow or it is how delphi deals with transparency?

Comment: Define "fixed". In other words, what do you want to appear under your image? And why are you setting `TransparentColor` and `TransparentColorValue`? And instead of telling us the version of Delphi that you are not using, could you tell us the version of Delphi that you are using?

Comment: Actually your form settings read as: "For each black pixel of the form show the pixel of the underlying desktop or window." The result you are seeing seems to be just that. It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe now i see how unclear my description is. Yes, transparent pixels show desktop, but what i see there is zoomed random part of desktop, not what actually placed beneath form

Comment: You still have not made any attempt to tell us what you want to achieve.  You are asking us how to get from A to B without telling us what B is.

Comment: @David Heffernan i want to see what is actually placed beneath form

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear what your goal is

Comment: Your problem description would benefit from a detail picture of the error. But please no full screen snapshots, reduce the picture to just demonstrate the error.

Comment: @TomBrunberg i have added picture

Comment: Since inside of the png is not black, form transparent properties have got nothing to do with it. You have not supplied enough information, how do you produce png contents?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i mentioned in main post that i am using PNG images, so their original extension is .png. I assume you mean this..

Comment: @lolbas - No, what I mean is 'transparent' properties supply full transparency, not partial. What we are seeing is probably what the png image currently contains. Why/how does it contain a zoomed part of the desktop? You've got to have some code somewhere.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz the way i load images is already in main post, and PNG source image is pure with nothing odd

Comment: @lolbas - I'd put a button on the form and in its click handler save the pngimage to a file. And see if it's still *pure* (does that mean a blank black image?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the form "shade" what's beneath it, use the forms `AlphaBlend` and `AlphaBlendValue` properties. The .png image doesn't have to be partially (alpha blended) transparent, but it can be.

---

If you want the form to be semi-transparent you use Alphablending, that's a limitation of Windows. In addition you can have a certain color fully transparent. In the following sample the forms color is clGray, which is also defined as the `Transparent color` property in addition to the `Transparent` property set to `True`. The image, aligned `alClient`, is 50% transparent, placed on a `TImage` which is set as transparent, but even so, it doesn't show up as semi-transparent unless you have AlphaBlending on. Again, this is a limitation of Windows. The best you can do is try with a fairly high value for `AlphaBlendingValue` (240..250) and a rather light image to find the right compromise.

[image]

Comment: Im curious about image you have inserted. So you frame has this star as background image, right? And those triangles that left to make a rectangle seem to be transparent. Do they show what actually lays under form or you have same bug as i do?

Comment: The form is rectangular and the `Color` and `TransparentColor` properties are both the same `clGray` and the `Transparent` property is `True`. You can get hint about the forms edges from the vertical lines of the IDE seen behind on the left and right. On the form I have a `TImage` to which I have loaded the star image. The star image is a rectangular .png where the pixels surrounding the star are transparent. The buttons and the trackbar (to adjust Alphablend) were added at designtime. The form (or image) has no artifacts from the code behind, it's  fully floating above the IDE behind.